# Using struct as a return value of function crash program

Tags: c++, struct, iostream

I wnat to use struct as a return value of fucntion but it doesn't work and i dont know why. Program crash when i run this program. I got RTE. What is wrong with this code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    struct Tablica{
        int T[201][201];
    };

    Tablica test(Tablica A, int m){
       if(m==1)return A;
       if(m%2 ==1){
            return test(A, m-1);
       }else{
           cout <<" #1 m " << m<<endl;
            Tablica B = test(A,m/2);
            cout <<" #2 m " << m<<endl;
            return B;
       }

    }
int main(){
    Tablica T;
   test(T,10);

}
```

[image]

Comment: look like a stackoverflow. And `Tablica ` is never touched in the function so I question its relevance...

Comment: Windows says that program has stoped working after i run this.

Comment: What happens when you try `test(T,1);`?

Comment: I don't know yet what the problem is, but why on Earth do you copy such a big struct over and over again? use `const Tablica&` as parameter type

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement at the end of `test()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no he isn't. All the branches return.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he is not, there is no way control reaches that point. But it would be better to omit explicit `else` in this case.

Comment: test(T,1) works fine.

Comment: Try it with a smaller matrix such as 51x51.

Comment: When i use  Tablica test(const Tablica& A, int m){ ... } program works fine for test(T,10) but still crush for test(T,500012)

Comment: Did you try to change the `else` part to `return test(A,m/2)`? This makes the function tail-recursive and allows massive compiler optimizations.

Comment: @MrLister Then the `else` branch should be omitted at all.

Comment: @Henrik this is short part of bigger program and i need separated variable.

Comment: @peterSweter Do you _really_ need all of the 40401 integers to be dynamic? Can't you do with a subset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets do the math: The structure is almost 160kB in size (201 * 201 * 4 (`sizeof(int)`)), each call creates two of those instances on the stack, one for the argument `A`, one for the variable `B`, meaning each call uses around 320kB of stack. You have three calls, so that's 960kB. ***Plus*** the original variable `T` in the `main` function upping the stack size used to 1120kB, which is over the 1024kB default process stack size used on Windows. Leading to a stack overflow and your crash.

The absolute simplest solution? Make the argument to the function a constant reference, i.e.

```
Tablica test(const Tablica& A, int m)
```

The problem with this is that you still have at least once instance every call on the stack, the variable `B`, so that just gives you a few more recursive calls before running out of stack.

A more complex solution would be to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the data in the structure, which puts the data on the heap and makes the structure several magnitudes smaller. This, together with the above solution to use a reference for the argument, is a more long-term solution, and will allow you quite a lot of recursive calls before running out of stack. It won't last forever though, the stack is a limited resource and sooner or later you will still run out.

The not recommended solution is to increase the stack size for the process, and that's only for when the last solution above hits the limit, but then you should start thinking about other and better designs to solve your problem before increasing the stack size.